# How do I replace NULL with zero in an SSIS expression?

Tags: ssis

I have two columns `ActivityCount` and `ParentValue`. I created an expression:

```
ROUND((ActivityCount / ParentValue) / 100,16) * 100
```

But the problem is it returns `NULL` for some columns and I wanted to replace `NULL` with `0`. I can't seem to find the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Expression:

```
ISNULL(ParentValue) || (ParentValue == 0) ? 0 : ROUND(ISNULL(ActivityCount) ? 0 : ActivityCount / ParentValue / 100,16) * 100
```

#### For readability:

```
ISNULL(ParentValue) || (ParentValue == 0) 
    ? 0 
    : ROUND((ISNULL(ActivityCount) 
                ? 0 
                : ActivityCount / ParentValue) / 100
             , 16) * 100
```

#### What it does:

- If *`ParentValue`* field is **`NULL`** or has **`Zero`**, you do not have to perform a calculation because you will encounter *`Divide by Zero`* error. So, simply exit the expression by returning **0**.
- If *`ActivityCount`* field is **`NULL`**, replace it with zero before performing the calculation.

#### Recommendation:

I would recommend using *`COALESCE`* on the source query to replace the NULL values with zeroes and the calculation, if possible.

Comment: Again a top quality answer @Siva +1

Comment: Thank You Siva that was awesome and Thank you to everybody else much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

Test with [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141184.aspx) (SSIS, not the SQL expression), use the [conditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141680.aspx) operator

```
ISNULL(ROUND((ActivityCount / ParentValue) / 100,16) * 100) ? 0 : ROUND((ActivityCount / ParentValue) / 100,16) * 100
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like below... it will help you...

```
ISNULL(ROUND((ActivityCount / ParentValue) / 100,16) * 100) || (ROUND((ActivityCount / ParentValue) / 100,16) * 100)= "" ? 0 : ROUND((ActivityCount / ParentValue) / 100,16
```

Answer (score 2):

I would have said:

```
ISNULL(ActivityCount) || ISNULL(ParentValue) ? 0 : ROUND((ActivityCount/ParentValue)/100,16)*100
```

That way you are testing the simplest cases that will cause a NULL result rather than calculating the end case multiple times in your conditional.

(That being said, any of these will technically work.)